# document.location.search.replace('?redirect=', '').replace('%2F', ''); is not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, angular, reactjs

document location search replace redirect to other page is working in chrome but

```
document.location.search.replace('?redirect=', '').replace('%2F', '');
```

is not working in Firefox, I am seeing to redirection infinite loop.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pz05d.png)

Comment: Could you please describe the point out what's problem in this post?

Comment: it is pretty difficult to even guess as to why some browsers don't like the result of this code when we don't have any examples of what the values you are working with are.  consider updating the question with a [mcve] of the issue.

Answer (score 1):

%2F is "/" in URL.

why don't you decode URL?

or you need to replace("\/","")

could you try it?